# How to perform two different events after clicking on menu item in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using lightning:buttonMenu. I need to perform two different actions after clicking menuitem.

1. After clicking document name, redirect to another page.(1st event)
2. After clicking delete icon, delete document.(2nd event)

[image]

Edit:

```
<lightning:buttonMenu variant="container" aura:id="menu" label="Manage">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfDocuments}" var="singleDoc">
    <lightning:menuItem value="{!singleDoc.Name}" label="{!singleDoc.Name}" >
           <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete"/>
     </lightning:menuItem>
   </aura:iteration>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

I tried this, but buttonIcon is not visible.

Comment: Hi Pooja, welcome to SFSE, please take moment to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. `Please suggest` type of quesitons are not really on topic here, make sure you update your post with what you have tried and/or where you are stuck for assistance. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to use another component for name and deleteIcon , but I am not getting how to assign it lightning:menuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lightning:menuItem works for only one action, either delete/redirect to details, if you want both action in one group , you should use lightning:buttonGroup instead of lightning:menuitem inside the lightning:buttonmenu. i achieved by using buttongroup. here is tested code please have look and let me know if you find any issues.

cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="listOfDocuments" type="List" default="[{'Name' : 'Document1', 'id':'1'},{'Name' : 'Document2','id':'2'},{'Name' : 'Document3','id':'3'}]"/>
<lightning:buttonMenu variant="container" aura:id="menu" label="Manage">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfDocuments}" var="singleDoc">
        <lightning:buttonGroup>
            <lightning:button value="{!singleDoc.Name}" name="detail" label="{!singleDoc.Name}" onclick="{!c.handledetailClick}" />
            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete" name="delete" value="{!singleDoc.id}" alternativeText="Delte" onclick="{!c.handledetailClick}"></lightning:buttonIcon>
        </lightning:buttonGroup>
    </aura:iteration>
```

controller.js

```
 "handledetailClick":function(component, event, helper) {
     var selectedButtonLabel = event.getSource().get("v.name");
    var selectedButtonvalue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    console.log(selectedButtonLabel);
    console.log(selectedButtonvalue);
    switch(selectedButtonLabel){
        case 'detail':

            break;
        case 'delete':

            break;
    }
}
```

},
     [image]